# NVidia drivers and 1440p

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm making the switch to Linux and in the process I've ran into a weird issue. After installing Nvidia drivers (I'm using a GTX 780) after reboot my 1440p monitor is not displaying.

I found where placed were saying to edit the x.conf. Since it's not created by default in Ubuntu Gnome (I'm using 14.10) I followed the process of booting into recovery mode and creating it. After creating it, Ubuntu didn't have....anything. It would boot, ask for credentials via the terminal, then go away after a few moments and nothing would come back.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu to get anything going again, so I'm tedious to try pushing forward from there. I plan on gaming, eventually, so I'm wanting to ensure I have the capability to do so.

I'm using this to update the driver: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates nvidia-settings-updates nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Albeit I understand it may not be directly driver related, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input. I'm working on going through the webpage that you linked now. Since I'm journying through Ubuntu to help me learn linux (I'm an IT admin with no linux experience... I need to change that)I'd like to learn how to roll back drivers for troubleshooting purposes (and in case something goes wrong here). 

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  As for rolling forward and backward is concerned, start with the latest driver apter adding the PPA: `apt-get install nvidia-346` and if that doesn't solve your question [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) on "how to roll back drivers" and drop a comment @Fabby.